# Prioritizing Greenlet workers for parallel read/writes/db access

Tags: python, multithreading, mongodb, parallel-processing, gevent

I need to read from 3 csv files of size 10gb each and write parts of the file to another 3 files. In the middle, there are some minor conditions involved and also a mongo query(6bil collection, properly indexed) for each row.

I was thinking using Gevent pools for the task but I am not sure how to prioritize the read tasks over writes,ensuring that read is finished before writers exit out.

I also dont want to block the writers until read is completely finished.

- I can spawn 3 readers which will put in a queue.
- I can spawn 20-25 io-processors which will read from queue, do mongodb call and write
  to a writer queue.
- I can then spawn 3 writers which read from write
  queue and write to the files.
- I can then do a joinall on the pool.

Now I can keep a queue timeout in io-processors and writers. But will that ensure that all of my readers have put the complete data in queue? Or is it possible to put a join on my readers at end of io-processors?

In short, I want to learn if there is any optimal approach which I could use to perform the task efficiently.